# How do I resolve a model backing MVC error if I have not made changes to the model backing my DbContext

Tags: entity-framework

I just tried to build a project I'm working on after doing a get latest in VS2015. After rebuilding and attempting to launch the project, I'm getting the following:

> The model backing the 'DevProjDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

Nowhere in the project  am I finding where the model backing the context has changed since my last get latest yesterday. Has anyone else encountered this error when the underlying model is unchanged?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about ASP.NET MVC, and yet it has three tags with conflicting version numbers. Please limit tags to those that actually categorize the specific library(ies) you're asking about.

Comment: @Alex Did you get the answer you need?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure of the target migration then better delete the migrationhistory table from your db and migration folder from you solution and re-add migrations to your code.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the "changes" to your database, use [Migrations to generate a script without changing the database.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167507/code-first-migrations-how-to-display-pending-model-changes)

```
Update-Database -Script
```